# Return different types from overloaded operator[] (templates?)

Tags: c++, templates

I have a collection class that needs to use the `operator[]` to access its data, however the data returned can be a number of different types (derived from a base class). Is there a way to use templates or even some other different way to overload the `operator[]` returning different types. If it is possible, examples or code snippets are much appreciated.

Comment: How is the data being stored in the first place?

Comment: Is it possible to determine the precise type simply by examining the call to `operator[]' in the compiler? In other words, can you deduce the type of the result from the type of the index? Templates are purely compile-time; by the time the code executes, they are irrelevant. So if you can't know the type until the code actually runs, templates cannot help you. But ordinary polymorphic classes with virtual functions probably can....

Comment: @rici: I understand what you are saying but it is possible to rely on the fact that users of the class know which type they want returned. With this I would be able use template specialization to have specific methods to return a specific type. The original idea was to use introspection to find the type at run time and have multiple overloaded methods with different return types, however this is not possible in C++. Another solution would have been to return a pointer to a base type that can be casted to a derived type, but I was trying to avoid pointers.

Comment: @jwodder: The data is stored in contiguous memory on the heap. Each data element is accessed through pointers.

Comment: You are going to have to make special methods for each type imo. What you want is basically to get the BaseClass* pointer and then dynamic_cast it to DerivedClass*, based on the actual type of the element. I don't think you can achieve this easily/elegantly.

Comment: @Akash If Felix is right (maybe even if he isn't) reconsider your design. If you need `dynamic_cast` or `static_cast` your design can be improved in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename ElementType>
class SpecialCollection
{
public:
    SpecialCollection(int length)
        : m_contents(length)
    {}
    ElementType& operator[](int index)
    {
        return m_contents[index];
    }
private:
    std::vector<ElementType> m_contents;
};

// Example usage:
int main()
{
    SpecialCollection<int> test(3);
    test[2] = 4;
    std::cout << test[1] << " " << test[2] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Looking at this code I ask myself: Why don't you just use a `std::vector`? But maybe you want to do a bit more in `operator[]()` method.

Comment: This is not the perfect solution for me, because what I wanted to do was although I was storing data as base types casts of derived type objects, I wanted to return the correct derived type when the data was accessed rather than returning the base type reference and having the user dynamic_cast the returned reference. However it seems like there is no solution that would work with the operator[].

Comment: @Akash IMO, best and safest you could do is to store a base class pointer in your collection. That is, if you can provide a common interface through the base class. Be mindful of slicing, though

Comment: @TeaOverflow, That is what I am doing; everything is stored as base class pointers to take advantage of polymorphism. However now to retrieve the data in its derived form, they must be dynamic_cast. Do you know if c++11 uses return types in its function signature meaning can I overload a function with only the return type changed (this would help me very much).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use the trailing return type deduction, though I may be misunderstanding you  completely.

```
auto operator[](int i) -> decltype(collection[i]) {
   return collection[i];
}
```

It's then upon the  compiler to deduce the return type, but, of  course, you cannot return variing types (at runtime). Just as you can't store them (safely) in one collection

Comment: This is really interesting and I had no idea that this was possible in C++, however this is not what I was looking for especially since it require C++11. The ideal solution or the solution that I was looking for will not work with the operator[].